# In Content Security Policy do more specific values completely replace general ones?

Tags: content-security-policy

I've looked at several CSP references, including a very good one at developer.mozilla.org, but can't find an answer to this: Suppose I want to allow everything from self and *.facebook.com, but only scripts from *.googleapis.com.  Do I have to repeat self and *.facebook.com in script-src?

In other words, is this sufficent?

```
Content-Security-Policy default-src 'self' *.facebook.com; script-src *.googleapis.com;
```

Or do I need to specify:

```
Content-Security-Policy default-src 'self' *.facebook.com; script-src 'self' *.facebook.com *.googleapis.com;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second variant is correct:

```
Content-Security-Policy
   default-src 'self' *.facebook.com;
   script-src 'self' *.facebook.com *.googleapis.com;
```

When you do specify the `script-src` directive in the policy, browser do not use any sources from `default-src` for scripts at all (do not performs fallback to `default-src`). Only sources from `script-src` will used.

So if your app loads scripts from `'self'` and `*.facebook.com`, you have to specify these in `script-src` independently of `default-src` content.